# How to locate an SVG using pseudo elements

Tags: html, css, svg, pseudo-element

I am trying to locate an SVG to have a look like this:
[image: The image]

And I want to do it by having a `::before` or `::after` pseudo-elements. But I can't because the SVG is too big and its first location is far from the borders of the parent element.

```
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title>Document</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>

<body>

<header>
    <h1>A modern <span>publishing platform</span> </h1>
    <p>Grow your audience and build your online brand</p>
    <div class="buttons">
        <button class="btn ">Start for Free</button>
        <button class="btn border ">Learn More</button>
    </div>
</header>

</body>

</html>


*{
box-sizing: border-box;
}

html{
font-size: 10px;
}


body{
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
font-family: Poppins;
position: relative;

}


header{
width: 100%;

padding:2rem;
text-align: center;
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
align-items: center;
color: white;
border-bottom-left-radius: 12rem;
position: relative;
z-index: -1;
background-image: linear-gradient(to right, 
hsl(13, 100%, 72%),
hsl(353, 100%, 62%));



h1{
    margin-top: 10rem;
    width: 100%;
    font-size: 2.7rem;

    span{
        display:block;
    }
    
}

p{
   font-size: 1.7rem;
   font-weight: 100; 
}


.buttons{

    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    .btn{
        padding: 1rem 2rem;
        background-color: white;
        border-radius: 3rem;
        border: none;
        margin: 0px 1rem;
        font-style: 400;
        font-family: Poppins;
        border: .1rem solid white;
        

    }

    .border{
        background-color: transparent;
        color: white;

        
        }

        margin-bottom: 10rem;

    }

    }

    header::before{
    content: url(images/bg-pattern-intro.svg);
    position: absolute;
    transform: scale(.1);

 

}
```

Can anyone tell me what to do? And why doesn’t the .svg locate itself close to the border of its parent in the first place?

Answer (score 0):

You need to set a `width` and a `height` to your pseudo-element. As-is, it's basically an empty `in-line` element with no actual content to prop it open, so it appears to be invisible. If you inspect in chrome, you'll see at least one of its dimensions is `0`.

In this case, I'd also make the pseudo-element `display: block` so it behaves more like a `div`.

It appears that when you set the `svg` image `url` as the `content` value then the default behavior is to fill the available container.

Here's a working example:

```css
header::before {
  content: url(https://dev.w3.org/SVG/tools/svgweb/samples/svg-files/feed.svg);
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<header></header>
```

Another option is to set the `svg` as a `background-image`. You'll probably also want to set a `background-size` value (in this case, `contain`) so that the background image scales based on its container instead of the `svg` file's inherent `viewBox` attribute.

```css
header::before {
  content: "";
  background: url(https://dev.w3.org/SVG/tools/svgweb/samples/svg-files/feed.svg) center center / contain no-repeat;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<header></header>
```

Comment: Side note: I didn't actually know that you could set image `url`s as `content` property values until I saw this question. Pretty neat, though I'm not sure if I'd ever use that... The more you know though!